# Regex avoid numeric and special characters and allow space between words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need validation for *Full name* text box which should avoid numeric and special characters, but allow space between words. See my JavaScript code here:

```
function jsPreventNumeric(obj) {
    obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gmi, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

It's working fine except it's not allowing space between words. I don't have much knowledge to edit that regex. Can anyone help me to adjust this regex to allow space also?

Comment: Remove `.replace(/\s+/g,"")`

Comment: Please paste code instead of linking it as image.

Comment: You know that you will remove all spaces from the string and it will leave out just the letters, so you will get something like 'IsankaThalagalaHadBreakfastThisMorning'?

Comment: @Azamantes It also removes upercase characters

Comment: @AUsr19532 He added `i` flag so it doesn't :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the first replace would still remove spaces as spaces are not in the range from a-z

Answer (score 1):

`\s` is the escape sequence for whitespace. So your second replace removes all whitepspaces explicitly. `/[^a-z]/` means all characters that are **not** characters from a-z. Add `\s` so it only removes characters that are not a-z or whitespace

```
function jsPreventNumeric(obj){
   obj.value.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gmi,"");
}
```

Comment: `/m` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the picture. Try this: ^[\\p{L} .'-]+$

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with:

```
obj.value = obj.value.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gmi, "");
```